# Problem with registering push notification on iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

If I register to push notifications on iOS 14 and iOS 15, methods
`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`
or
`didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`
are called as they should be.

When I register on iOS 16, I don't get calls. And `UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` is True as it should not be.

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        registerForPushNotifications()
        return true
    }
    
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        print("Device Token: \(token)")
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("NOTIFICATION ERROR: \(error)")
    }
    
    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            .requestAuthorization(
                options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { [weak self] granted, _ in
                    print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
                    guard granted else { return }
                    self?.getNotificationSettings()
                }
    }
    
    func getNotificationSettings() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but an observation You should not expect the token to be in a specific format. It is an opaque value that you should persist to your server.  The format of the token has changed in the past and may well change in the future.

Comment: Also, you should not tie the registration process to the approval response. The notification permission is to *show* notifications, not register for remote notifications. You should register for remote notifications at each launch and be prepared for the token to change at any time.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to call `registerForRemoteNotifications` before calling your `registerForPushNotifications` function. Something like below.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        registerForPushNotifications()
    }
    return true
}
```

Below is the comment mentioned by apple :

> // Calling this will result in either application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: or application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: to be called on the application delegate. Note: these callbacks will be made only if the application has successfully registered for user notifications with registerUserNotificationSettings:, or if it is enabled for Background App Refresh.

```
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
open func registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Comment: This fixed the error for me, thanks!